# Mouse position within child elements regardless of zoom, scroll, size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get calculated mouse coordinates within the page elements.

Please check jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/t8w9k6gu/

```js
$('#p1, #p2, #p3').on('click mousemove touchmove', function(ev){
    var target = ev.originalEvent.currentTarget;
    var offset = $(target).offset();
    
    var x = ev.originalEvent.pageX;
    var y = ev.originalEvent.pageY;
    
    $(coords).html(x + ', ' + y);
    
    $(elm).html(target.id + ' {' + offset.left + ', ' + offset.top + '}');
    
});


var main = $('#main');
var content = $('#content');
var zoom = $('#zoom');
var coords = $('#coords');
var scroll = $('#scroll');
var zoomv = 0.5;
$(content).css({zoom: zoomv});
$('#headh').html($('#head').height());
$('#headsize').on('click', function(ev){
    $('#headbig').toggle();
    $('#headh').html($('#head').height());
});
$('#zoomin').on('click', function(){
    zoomv += .1;
    $(content).css({
        zoom: zoomv
    });
    $(zoom).html(zoomv);
});
$('#zoomout').on('click', function(){
    if(zoomv < .2){
        return;
    }
    zoomv -= .1;
    $(content).css({
        zoom: zoomv
    });
    $(zoom).html(zoomv);
});

$(main).on('scroll', function(ev){
    $(scroll).html($(main).scrollLeft() + ', ' + $(main).scrollTop());
});
```

```css
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#head{
    border:2px #880 solid;
}
#headbig{
    border:2px #ccc dashed;
    height:50px;
    display: none;
}
#main{
    overflow:auto;
    height:186px;
    background-color:#f00;
}
#content{
    height:0;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    background-color: #00f;
}
#p1, #p2, #p3{
    background-color:#0ff;
    margin:10px;
    width:600px;
    height:800px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="wrap">
        <div id="head">
            <input type="button" id="zoomin" value="Zoom in" />
            <input type="button" id="zoomout" value="Zoom Out" />
            <input type="button" id="headsize" value="Resize head" />
            <br />
            Mouse coords: <span id="coords">0, 0</span>
            <br />
            Element offset: <span id="elm">null, 0, 0</span>
            <br />
            Main scroll: <span id="scroll">0, 0</span>
            <br />
            Content zoom: <span id="zoom">0.5</span>
            <br />
            Head height: <span id="headh">0</span>
            <div id="headbig"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="p1">
                    <h1>Page 1</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="p2">
                    <h1>Page 2</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="p3">
                    <h1>Page 3</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this example, `page` elements are 600x800 pixels.
What I need is to get calculated mouse position within any of the `page` elements, regardless of zoom value, scrollbar positions, head element size.

So, for example, if mouse pointer is on the bottom right corner of any `page` element, coordinates should always be `{600,800}`, top-left of the `page` should always be `{0,0}`, and center of the `page` should be `{300,400}`. No matter of zoom, scroll, head size.

I have tried many combinations of calculating by using mouse event (pageX/pageY), `page` element offsets, scroll position, zoom, ..., but I can't find the right way to correctly calculate position within the `page` elements.

This layout is a part of much more complex application, so layout (html, css) can not be changed. I need to find how to calculate position with this exact layout.

I need to make this work on PC Chrome browser, and on mobile iOS Safari and Android Chrome browsers.

Any help, suggestions, pointers to reading, etc. would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The closest I could get so far is by using `getBoundingClientRect` to calculate position as:

```
var bb = target.getBoundingClientRect();    
var x = ev.originalEvent.pageX / zoomv - bb.left;
var y = ev.originalEvent.pageY / zoomv - bb.top;
```

Jsfiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/t8w9k6gu/1/

It is good enough for my needs at this moment, but still not perfectly correct. So, if you can suggest some improvements, please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be easier if you don't use zoom and instead use transform scale. Zoom adjusts the size then renders, where as scale renders, then adjusts the size which leaves the coordinates system alone.

Then use ev.offsetX and ev.offsetY? They should give you the coordinates you are after. This will give you between 0,0 and 600,800 in chrome at all zoom levels.

```
$('#zoomin').on('click', function(){
    zoomv += .1;
    $(content).css({
        'transform-origin': 'left top',
        transform: 'scale(' + zoomv + ')'
    });
    $(zoom).html(zoomv);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lya59L/

Comment: Your suggestion gives correct mouse position. But, transform scale gives different result than zoom. Difference can be seen at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nasbo0yz/
I need same scaling result as provided by zoom.

Comment: You are right, it looks I can make something the similar way you did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your current cursor value is relative to you div position so you need to exclude div's left and top value from current cursor position.

i have take two variables a and b to take left and top position of current div and then exclude it from x and y values.

I have updated http://jsfiddle.net/t8w9k6gu/8/

```
 function(ev){
    var target = ev.originalEvent.currentTarget;
    var offset = $(target).offset();
    var a = offset.left
    var b = offset.top
    var x = ev.originalEvent.pageX;
    var y = ev.originalEvent.pageY;

    $(coords).html((parseInt(x)-parseInt(a)) + ', ' + (parseInt(y)-parseInt(b)));

    $(elm).html(target.id + ' {' + offset.left + ', ' + offset.top + '}');  
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but your suggestion does not give expected results with zoom values other than 1.

Comment: it should be working with other zoom values, can you paste jsfiddle link with changed zoom value for which its not working ?